# Inserting a selection from another file into a table - Format error on repetition

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word

I have a block of code that only generates a formatting error when running multiple times.

The purpose of the application is to copy a table row from another document and paste it into a specific table in the main document. In the other document there is nothing else than this table row.

The error is now the following:
The table has two columns. The first row is correctly appended, but the second row is pasted as a complete block into the first cell, so the second column is neither created nor filled. If I append more rows, they are always nested and inserted in the first cell.

Screenshot:

[image]

```
Dim wddoc As Document

If CheckBox700400.Value = True Then
    Set wddoc = Documents.Open(file1)
    wddoc.Activate
    With ActiveDocument:
        Selection.WholeStory
        Selection.Copy
    End With
    ThisDocument.Activate
    With Selection:
        .GoTo what:=wdGoToTable, Count:=4
        .GoTo what:=wdGoToLine
        .PasteAndFormat (wdTableAppendTable)
    End With
    wddoc.Close
End If

If CheckBox700300.Value = True Then
    Set wddoc = Documents.Open(file2)
    wddoc.Activate
    With ActiveDocument:
        Selection.WholeStory
        Selection.Copy
    End With
    ThisDocument.Activate
    With Selection:
        .GoTo what:=wdGoToTable, Count:=4
        .GoTo what:=wdGoToLine
        .PasteAndFormat (wdTableAppendTable)
    End With
    wddoc.Close
End If
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "In the other document there is nothing else than this table row." That statement is incorrect. A document that contains a single row table also contains an empty paragraph that comes after the table. In selecting the entire document you are copying both the table and the final empty paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto line is doing exactly what you asked it to do.  It is going to the first line of text in the table and inserting after that line of text.  Its more likely that after selecting the table you need to collapse the range so that you insert at the end of the table.

Have a look at the following code.  I'd recommend using F8 to step through your code and the code below and then making any tweaks you need to the code below to get it to do exactly what you want.

```
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Set myDoc = ActiveDocument
    
    Dim wddoc As Word.Document
    Dim myRange As Word.Range
    
    If CheckBox700400.Value = True Then
    
        Set wddoc = Documents.Open(file1)
        wddoc.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).Copy
            
        Set myRange = myDoc.Tables.Item(4).Range
        myRange.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        myRange.PasteAndFormat wdTableAppendTable
        
        wddoc.Close
        
    End If

    If CheckBox700300.Value = True Then
    
        Set wddoc = Documents.Open(file2)
        wddoc.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).Copy
            
        Set myRange = myDoc.Tables.Item(4).Range
        myRange.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        myRange.PasteAndFormat wdTableAppendTable
        
        wddoc.Close
        
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) In fact, it was my intention that the table is always populated at the top but it works beautifully that way too. Your solution is much more efficient, thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Dim DocSrc As Document, DocTgt As Document, Rng As Range
Set DocTgt = ActiveDocument

If CheckBox700400.Value = True Then
    Set DocSrc = Documents.Open(file1)
    DocSrc.Tables(1).Range.Copy
    Set Rng = DocTgt.Tables(4).Range
    Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Rng.PasteAndFormat (wdTableAppendTable)
    DocSrc.Close
End If

If CheckBox700300.Value = True Then
    Set DocTgt = Documents.Open(file2)
    DocSrc.Tables(1).Range.Copy
    Set Rng = DocTgt.Tables(4).Range
    Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Rng.PasteAndFormat (wdTableAppendTable)
    DocSrc.Close
End If
```

Alternatively, if both tables have the same format:

```
Dim DocSrc As Document, DocTgt As Document, Rng As Range
Set DocTgt = ActiveDocument

If CheckBox700400.Value = True Then
    Set DocSrc = Documents.Open(file1)
    Set Rng = DocTgt.Tables(4).Range
    Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Rng.FormattedText = DocSrc.Tables(1).Range.FormattedText
    DocSrc.Close
End If

If CheckBox700300.Value = True Then
    Set DocTgt = Documents.Open(file2)
    Set Rng = DocTgt.Tables(4).Range
    Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Rng.FormattedText = DocSrc.Tables(1).Range.FormattedText
    DocSrc.Close
End If
```

Comment: Looking at the code in the question I think you've got the source and target documents the wrong way round.

Comment: True, but if you turn it around, this solution also works. Thanks for your approach and your help :)

Comment: «I think you've got the source and target documents the wrong way round» Code revised.